# Passing data from DetailView to CreateView django

Tags: python, django

I have a `UserDetailView`

which has a url of `/user/1000`/ and displays `object.id` equals to 1000

Within my `UserDetailView` I have an ADD button which redirects to `UserNumberCreateView`

In the next view which is the `UserNumberCreateView`
I want to pass the 1000 value to `UserNumberCreateView` as primary key, how can I pass the 1000 value to my UserNumberCreateView without submitting the UserNumberCreateView?

Answer (score 1):

There are already [questions about redirecting with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django%20redirect%20with%20parameters).

If you mean that the button **links** to the UserNumberCreateView, you may just make its URL like  `/user/1000/numbercreate/` and in the template href="{% url 'app:numbercreate' object.id %}".

Comment: I dont want to pass it in the URL just within the view